# Are there recesses during the U.N. Security Council?

Tags: united-nations, procedure

Are there recesses during the U.N. Security Council? I have watched a dozen of UNSC meetings and none of them had recesses. Is it because most meetings only last a few hours like 3-4 maximum? What happens if the meeting lasts 5-6 hours? Are the people in there expected to stay there throughout the whole thing without any break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there recesses during the U.N. Security Council?

There is a procedure, but it is not called recess. *To suspend the meeting* would seem closest to recess or a break, such as for a meal, etc.

From [Provisional Rules of Procedure](https://www.un.org/securitycouncil/content/rop/chapter-6), Chapter VI: Conduct of Business, Rule 33:

> The following motions shall have precedence in the order named over all principal motions and draft resolutions relative to the subject before the meeting:
>
> 1. To suspend the meeting;
> 2. To adjourn the meeting;
> 3. To adjourn the meeting to a certain day or hour;
> 4. To refer any matter to a committee, to the Secretary-General or to a rapporteur;
> 5. To postpone discussion of the question to a certain day or indefinitely; or
> 6. To introduce an amendment.
>
> Any motion for the suspension or for the simple adjournment of the meeting shall be decided without debate.

The following mentions the misuse of "recess" in terms of Rule 33.

From [books.google](https://books.google.com/books?id=8M9LBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA284&dq=un%20security%20council%20%22recess%22%20rules%20-model&pg=PA284#v=onepage&q=un%20security%20council%20%22recess%22%20rules%20-model&f=false):

[image: Image from Google Books]